# Qual a origem da palavra "profetas" para a designar os habitantes do Porto Santo?

Tags: etimologia, expressões, português-europeu, origem-histórica, significado-em-contexto

Qual a origem e significado da palavra "profetas" para a designar os habitantes do Porto Santo? em que século surgiu ?

Comment: Eu não sabia que chamam "profeta" aos habitantes de Porto Santo e acho a expressão devéras interessante.Se alguém souber reponder faça favor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo este site turístico sobre Porto Santo, isto está relacionado com uma [lenda sobre a ilha,](http://www.visitportosanto.pt/pt-pt/o-porto-santo/lendas/lenda-dos-profetas) que remota ao séc. XVI, acerca de um habitante (pastor eremita) que se fez passar por profeta e causou desacatos na região.

Comment: Até que enfim alguém redesvenda o mistério do profeta de Porto Santo. (Eu não sabia desta, mas fico a saber...)